# Split a numeric string to a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have fetched a list using pandas, but the numeric is like a numeric string. I am trying to convert it to a list of integers.

```
excel_frame = read_excel(args.path, sheet_name=1, verbose=True, na_filter=False)
data_need = excel_frame['Dependencies'].tolist()
print(data_need)

intStr = data_need.split(',')
map_list = map(int, intStr)
print(map_list)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
$python ExcelCellCSVRead.py -p "C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\Integra\Intest\first.xlsx"
Reading sheet 1
['187045, 187046']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExcelCellCSVRead.py", line 31, in <module>
    intStr = data_need.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The target output must be like this -> `[187045, 187046]`. The current output is coming out like this ->`['187045, 187046']`

I am pretty sure I have followed suggested approach to resolve the issue, yet it is throwing error.

Regards

data_need

Comment: Please, provide a sample of the input data and the desired output.

Comment: So there is only one value (one list ) in column `Dependencies` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
data_need = excel_frame['Dependencies'].tolist()
```

returns a `list`. So you can't split it further.

#### Change your existing code to this:

```
intStr = data_need[0].split(',') ## if you have only 1-element in data_need
map_list = list(map(int, intStr))
print(map_list)
```

#### Tested on your sample:

```
In [1000]: data_need = ['187045, 187046']                                                                                                                                                                   

In [1001]: intStr = data_need[0].split(',')                                                                                                                                                                 

In [1002]: map_list = list(map(int, intStr))                                                                                                                                                                

In [1003]: print(map_list)                                                                                                                                                                                  
[187045, 187046]
```